# what will be the exact code of below vb code in java because i am not getting the same encrypted value

Tags: java

' Encrypts a string using tripple DES
    Private Function TripleDESEncrypt(ByVal str As String) As TripleDESEncryptResult

```
    ' 3DES Encryption
    ' Generate KEY/IV pair for your local 3DES encrpytion on xmlCard

    ' Create a new 3DES CryptoProvider and generate KEY/IV pair for encryption
    Dim m_cryptoProvider As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
    m_cryptoProvider.GenerateIV() 
    m_cryptoProvider.GenerateKey() 

    Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream = _
      New CryptoStream(stream, m_cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor, _
                          CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    Dim Input() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str)

    cryptoStream.Write(Input, 0, Input.Length)
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()

    ' Convert to base64, so it'll be XML-friendly
    Dim encryptedCardString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray())

    cryptoStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Dispose()

    Return New TripleDESEncryptResult(encryptedCardString, m_cryptoProvider.Key, m_cryptoProvider.IV)

End Function
```

Comment: unable to identify logic behind the GenerateKey and GenerateIV methods

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to convert above vb.net code into java/

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: yes i tried number of codes but not getting exact encrypted value as same as vb.net.

Comment: Converting entire code into jave or you want to decrypt the code in java after it was encrypted by vb.net

Comment: i just want do the encryption same as above code in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is in java for 3DES encryption and decryption. please try with this code. I hope it will help you

```
   private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
            public static final String DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DESede"; //"DESede/ECB/NoPadding";
            private KeySpec ks;
            private SecretKeyFactory skf;
            private Cipher cipher;
            byte[] arrayBytes;
            private String myEncryptionKey;
            private String myEncryptionScheme;
            SecretKey key;

            public PasswordEncryption_TrippleDES() throws Exception {
                myEncryptionKey =  "ThisIsSpartaThisIsanilku";
                myEncryptionScheme = DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
                arrayBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
                ks = new DESedeKeySpec(arrayBytes);
                skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
                key = skf.generateSecret(ks);
            }


            public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
                String encryptedString = null;
                try {
                    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                    byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
                    byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
                    encryptedString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedText));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return encryptedString;
            }


            public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
                String decryptedText=null;
                try {
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
                    byte[] encryptedText = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString);
                    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
                    decryptedText= new String(plainText);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return decryptedText;
            }
 public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
        {
            PasswordEncryption_TrippleDES td= new PasswordEncryption_TrippleDES();

            String target="data for encyption";
            String encrypted=td.encrypt(target);
            String decrypted=td.decrypt(encrypted);

            System.out.println("String To Encrypt: "+ target);
            System.out.println("Encrypted String:" + encrypted);
            System.out.println("Decrypted String:" + decrypted);

        }
```

Comment: i tried your code Anil Reddy but still not getting the same. but thanks for your help..

Comment: Did you get any exception ?

Comment: no execute it successfully but encrypted value is not same as vb.net code.

Comment: i just need to write code which encrypted value should be same as vb.net code encrypted value.

Comment: Encrypted value depending on key which you are using in the vb.net code. use same key in this code along with same data. you will get same encrypted value

Comment: yes but i have no idea about generatekey and generateiv method that what would they return? , so unable to identify the keys

Comment: Key should be mandatory for the encryption process. Without key we can decrypt. Please take a key first. then apply same in the above code. It should give you the exact results.